# android TCP client unable to display data sent from C Server via wi-fi

Tags: android, tcp, client, bufferedreader

I'm kinda new to android socket programming. My android program simply connects to a server (written in c,executed in the console) and must display the content being sent from the server (something like "hi client"). I have textview's for displaying whether the connection is being established or not and another edittext for sending the client's message to the server. The system is connected via Wi-fi. The server is able to recieve messages from my android client but android client is not displaying the message sent by the server. The code snippet for the reading from server part is:

```
 private TextView MsgFromServer; //defination
```

// here is the code for the connection and starting new thread etc

```
   final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));    


   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                try {
                                    while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                                        MsgFromServer.append(line);
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

Also I tried doing something like this:

final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

```
                   line=in.readLine().toString(); //string type

                      handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                          MsgFromServer.setText(line);
                                  }
                                  }
```

both approaches are not working for me.The message I send from the client to the server reaches there properly whereas the other direction communication is not happening. Also I've tested my C server with a simple C client and the message passing is happening smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the client behave? Is it waiting at in.readLine() ?

Be sure the server sends "Hi client\n" (with the lineend).

in.readLines() only returns when a lineend \n is found.

Is the new Runnable running? If you change the code
a little to

```
                          try {
                                     MsgFromServer.append("going to read a line..");
                              while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                                    MsgFromServer.append(line);
                                }
```

then do you see that?

Comment: sorry... my bad.. i cleaned the project and implemented your suggestion.. it worked!